# Azure Service Bus deployment

Tags: servicebus

I am using the Azure service bus for message transfer between different services. I have written a simple windows application to give to the 3rd party customer to test that their system can talk to the service bus. All it does is post a message on a button click and receive the message back from the same queue.

This system works fine on my development machine but when I test it on another machine it fails timing out when trying to post. Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll & Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll have both been deployed with the application.

Is there an SDK that I need to install on the deployment machine as well. I have looked but all I seem to find are SDK's for VS. The application is running in .NET 4.0 due to target the old target machines that we have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to a network issue on some machines. Nothing else needed to be installed